# COUNTIF function with wild cards isn't working

Tags: excel, vba, countif

Have an excel sheet, I am trying to do a `=COUNTIF(29:29, *TBB*)`. however these wild cards dont seem to be working. Any Ideas.

Comment: Pattern is a string. String must be enclosed with doublequotes. `=COUNTIF(29:29, "*TBB*")`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
=COUNTIF(29:29,"*TBB*")
```